# Python rotating image with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on this open cv python project. I was able to load the image, plot the RGB,and change image to grey scale. However, once I try to rotate the image, nothing pops up in the terminal. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##### loading the image 

coffeeImage = cv2.imread("coffee.jpeg")
blue, green, red = cv2.split(coffeeImage)

img_matplotlib = cv2.merge([red, green, blue])

#####  plotting RGB image

plt.subplot(122)
plt.title("RGB")
plt.imshow(img_matplotlib)
plt.show()

#### Changing image to grey-scale

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(coffeeImage,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow('grey-scale',grayImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#### rotate the image 



(h, w) = grayImage.shape[:2]
center = (w / 2, h / 2)
 
angle90 = 90
scale = 1.0

rotatedImage = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle90, scale)
rotated90 = cv2.warpAffine(grayImage, rotatedImage, (h, w))

cv2.imshow('Rotated Image', rotated90)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thanks

Comment: were you able to `cv2.imshow('Rotated Image",rotatedImage)` ?  Then your problem is your `cv2.warpAffine()` result.

Comment: The rotate code looks fine to me. As long as `cv2.imshow('grey-scale',grayImage)` works, it seems you should make it through rotation OK. If you are always rotating increments of 90 degrees, [rotate](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4ad01c0978b0ce64baa246811deeac24) is easier and actually works better.

Comment: Once I installed opencv and matplotlib on my own computer, your code worked fine on my machine.  I had to close the first image with the close x, then the other waitkey worked.  Did you close your original image?

Comment: Your code seems fine. As an alternative you can use numpy rotate (numpy.rot90) as long as rotation is in multiples of 90 degrees and no scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize the waitkey(0) had special buttons to move to next picture lol

thanks to all of you!